# How to listen switch MotionEvent.AXIS when an android gamepad joystick is useing?

Tags: android, gamepad

I try to listen android gamepad's joystick `MotionEvent` in View.

when i use `public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)`, I don't know which MotionEvent.AXIS i should use in the method `event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_XXXXXX)`

for example:

left joystick :

```
event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X),event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_Y)
```

right joystick :

```
event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_Z),event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_RZ)
```

But I don't know which to use(`MotionEvent.AXIS_X`  or  `MotionEvent.AXIS_Z`)?

Is there some API to select `MotionEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

just use all types   event.getAxisValue, and judge  the value!=0